# VBA navigating IE javascript link

Tags: javascript, vba, excel

First post. No idea how to do this.
Never retrieved data from a website before.
Can navigate through VBA to a page with options to open reports, but at this point everything goes from html to Javascript to open reports. How would I go about opening the report? No problems in navigating to the page or pulling down the data from the table

```
<div id='delivery_reports' class='menu' onMouseover='aMenu(this);'>
<table>

<tr>
<td nowrap><a href="javascript:handleHyperlink('finish.do')"
class="mainSubLink">finish Report</a></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td nowrap><a href="javascript:handleHyperlink('start.do')"
class="mainSubLink">start Report</a></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td nowrap><a href="javascript:handleHyperlink('control.do')"
class="mainSubLink">control report</a></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td nowrap><a href="javascript:handleHyperlink('data_start.do')"
class="mainSubLink">data start Report</a></td>
</tr>

</table>
</div>
```

How would i navigate to the control report for example?

Any help appreciated, thankyou

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `IE.Navigate` method (assuming here that IE is your InternetExplorer object).  You would do something like `IE.Navigate "javascript:handleHyperlink('control.do')"`

It's important to note that the page's HTML document will be reloaded (or rather, it was the one time I needed to use this), therefore any variables you have referencing HTML Elements on the page will have to be re-assigned after you use the Navigate method.

A more complete example:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument

    Set ie = New InternetExplorer

    ie.Navigate "http://www.yoururl.com"

    'Wait for page to load
    Do While ie.Busy Or Not ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Set doc = ie.document

    'Do whatever manipulation of the HTML document you need

    ie.Navigate "javascript:handleHyperlink('control.do')"

    'Wait for page to load
    Do While ie.Busy Or Not ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop

    'Reassign document
    Set doc = ie.document

    'Further manipulation

End Sub
```

This is just how I've found to do it based on making some code work for my own needs.  There may be an even better way.

### Addendum

You can execute JavaScript functions by using two methods (that I know of).  The first is the `execScript` and the other is `FireEvent`.  Remember that `IE` is your `InternetExplorer` object.

**execScript**

```
IE.document.all.Item 
Call IE.document.parentWindow.execScript("handleShowAllLines()", "JavaScript")
```

Additionally, since the js code is tied to a button, you can also use the **FireEvent** as such:

```
IE.Document.GetElementsByTagName("showAllLinesButton").Item(0).FireEvent("onclick")
```

This method assumes that there is only one button with the name "showAllLinesButton".  If that is not the case, you'd have to adjust the index of 0 in the `.Item(0)` to be the index of the correct button that needs clicked.

I have not tested either method, and I am not completely sure of the advantages/drawbacks of one approach over the other.

Comment: Thankyou @JoshuaRoss, worked perfectly.                               function handleShowAllLines() 
 {
  document.gloReportForm.showAllLinesButton.disabled=true;
  handleLink();
 }                                                                     <input type="button" name="showAllLinesButton" value="Show All Lines" onclick="handleShowAllLines();"/>                                      How would I call on this?

Comment: Thankyou! sadly this time both pieces of your second solution code produced an error :(

Comment: May I have the URL of the website you are trying to do this on?  That's the only way I will for sure be able to test.  Sorry that my additions didn't help!

Comment: Oh dear, the site is private and passworded. Only accessible from certain computers also. Is there anything i could provide to help ascertain why it isn't working?